# return early from some method when full computation is not needed

Tags: c++, refactoring

I have a function simillar to this:

```
void fillset(std::set<int>& myset)
{

while(...) {
object[i]->fillset(myset);
}

if(...) 
    otherfillset(myset)

}
```

now I notice that often this function is used like this:

```
bool isAllowed() {

std::set<int> myset;

fillset(myset);

return !myset.empty();


}
```

Now, calling the whole fillset() method is useless for this case, as it takes some time to execute.
I could in this case return as soon as one element is found.
Is there a simple way to refactor this without having to duplicate the code of fillset?
I was thinking of something like this:

```
template<bool return_as_soon_as_not_empty>

void fillset(std::set<int>& myset)
{

while(...) {
object[i]->fillset(myset);
if( return_as_soon_as_not_empty && !myset.empty()) {
return;
}
}

if(...) 
    otherfillset(myset)

}
```

how do you feel about this? any other idea is welcome

Comment: You could have an optional `maximum` parameter which sets the maximum number of objects to fill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you actually want to do, is to create a new function `canFillSet()` and call that instead.

All approaches to 'fix' the `fillSet()` method will cause it to do something that is not obvious from its name and signature => these methods are roads to disaster, they will cause bugs when the program is modified later on.

Comment: is there a way I can implement canFillSet() without retyping the logic of fillSet() ?

Comment: Probably yes: if the implementation of `fillSet()` is properly modularized, you can reuse the functions it uses. You might also first do copy/paste and then refactor your code to reduce redundancies. In any case, I really think, the two functions should appear right next to one another in the source to reduce the chance that they get out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this changes the meaning of `fillset()`. It is no longer filling the set with all elements, it fills it with only the first.

A better solution would be to cascade the `isAllowed()` through the objects

```
bool isAllowed() {
    while (...) {
        if (object[i]->isAllowed())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can truly guarantee that there are no side-effects of filling the set, you could make your recommended change. But if that set needs to get filled for something else to work properly, you risk changing that behavior.

You could call the early-return variable something like `single_fill` or something to imply that you are only looking for one object to fill with instead of the whole possible set. You should also consider making that variable optional and default to `false`.